# Removing elements from a List which respect a condition on the index

Tags: c#, list, linq

I'm asked to create a function which removes all the elements from a list of integers respecting a specified condition i.e. the element is multiple of his index.

It is very easy to do it with iterations and things like that but I wanted to do it in a "cuter" way just to get into more complex writing codes, Linq and Lambdas.

That's what I've tried

```
public static List<int> MultipleOfIndex(List<int> xs) =>
    xs.RemoveAll(s => (s % xs.IndexOf(s) == 0));
```

but I get the following error: error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

I can't really understand where I'm doing an implicit conversion since my logic is this: I want to remove all the elements *s* where s modulo his index is 0.
I'd like to have an explanation and also I'd like to see how can I also implement it with Where/Select clauses.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you cant have modulo 0...so what do you do with first item of your list?

Comment: the first item of the list is accettable if and only if is equal to 0 so yeah, i should add the particular case.. I suppose it is like (s => (s == 0 && xs.IndexOf(s) == 0) || s % xs.IndexOf(s) == 0)

Comment: in anyways RemoveAll  doenst return a list, it return an int which represents the number of items which are ok with the predicate

Comment: Do you need a *new* list or you want to modify the original?

Comment: oh, damn, that's true! found the error! how can I return the list with removed items after executing RemoveAll, then?

Comment: it's the same, but I'd prefer to have the same list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to modify the original list, you can use the following (note that you need to handle a divide-by-zero)

```cs
public static List<int> MultipleOfIndex(List<int> xs)
{
    xs.RemoveAll(s => xs.IndexOf(s) == 0 && s != 0 || s % xs.IndexOf(s) == 0);
    return xs;
}
```

A more efficient version might be:

```cs
public static List<int> MultipleOfIndex(List<int> xs)
{
    for (var i = xs.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if(i == 0 && xs[i] != 0 || xs[i] % i == 0)
            xs.RemoveAt(i);
    }
    return xs;
}
```

---

If you want to create a new list, you can use LINQ

```cs
public static List<int> MultipleOfIndex(List<int> xs) =>
    xs.Where((s, index) => index == 0 && s == 0 || s % index != 0).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is the most accurate answer!

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to map the list to a list of tuples, with the first element being the index and the second the value, the reason being that `removeAll()` might be parallel, thusly making the algorithm inconsistent. This way I believe that you also won't get issues (although I didn't try this).

Answer (score 0):

you just use Where predicate (with the problem of index = 0)

```
var result = listofInt.Where((x, i) => i != 0 && x % i != 0).ToList();
```

`i` represents the index of item x in the listOfInt